# creating new df after every iteration (pandas, python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

is it possible to create a new df after every iteration? with [i] being the iteration, it should generate df0, df1, df2, etc.. to the MAX NUMBER range as presented in the example:

```
for i in range(MAX_NUMBER + 1):
   df[i] = pd.read_csv(f"C:/Users/Desktop/{i}.csv")
```

the original codes are functions that loop multiple times. however, for simplicity, i've use read.csv for the example.

kindly advise. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read file and assign it to a dictionary key with key being the name of dataframe as follows:

```
dfs = {}
for i in range(MAX_NUMBER + 1):
   dfs[f'df{i}'] = pd.read_csv(f"C:/Users/Desktop/{i}.csv")
```

Then you can access each df by its name:

```
dfs['df0']
```

Answer (score 3):

Try creating array and append df as you progress through for loop. like this,

```py
df = []
for i in range(MAX_NUMBER + 1):
    df.append(pd.read_csv(f"C:/Users/Desktop/{i}.csv"))
```

and when you need to access, you can use index like `df[0]`, `df[1]`.